# Stop launching app when Play Services are outdated

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play-services, chromecast

For my Android app I use Google Play Services for things like: Chromecast, Maps and analytics.

In my `build.gradle` file I compile version 12.0.0:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0"
```

The problem is that the app crashes when people don't have version 12 or newer installed on their device.

So what I did is the following:

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

And a small class to check if play services is up-to-date or installed:

```java
public boolean checkIfInstalled(Context applicationContext) {
    try {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(applicationContext);

        // Version is out of date
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(applicationContext);
            builder.setMessage("Google Play Services is required to use this app. Install Play Services or update to the latest version to continue.");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Go to Play store", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.i("PlayServicesCheck", "clicked on the button");
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            return false;
        }

        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In onCreate (when the app launches) I call this function to check if everything is alright. The function returns false when it's outdated. So my code works at this point.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    boolean isInstalled = checkIfInstalled(getApplicationContext());

    // this works, I get the right value back from the checkIfInstalled function
    if (isInstalled) {
        Log.i("PlayServicesCheck", "Installed");
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        Log.i("PlayServicesCheck", "Not Installed");
        // Give alert, stop everything else
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

But how do I stop the app from launching when this happens? Right now it says: "version outdated" but it will still continue to start the app which leads to a crash.

Thanks

Comment: call 'finishAffinity()' when playservice not available. In your code, in the else part

Comment: @VinayakB That doesn't work, I suspect because the ChromeCast library I use still gets loaded this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finishAndRemoveTask`.

The problem with checking from the store that it takes time for Google to deploy the version to all the servers, therefore, it can happen that you're forced to update but when you enter into the store you still don't see the new version.

In any case, it would be better if you would have a server where you return the minimum version. This will let you fine tune on which changes you want to force the user to download and on which you don't. It can sometimes be disturbing for the user if each version is forced.

Comment: I still have this error when I add finishAndRemoveTask. I can also set the minimum version in the app (which is 12.0 in this case). Everything newer is fine,